# Accelerometer in Service

Tags: android, android-service

I am trying to use the accelerometer in `Service` (to run in background indefinitely) for taking accelerometer data for my research group.

`public class AccService extends Service implements SensorEventListener`

My Question is that when I register the sensor, should I pass the registerListener with handler parameter (another thread) or should I just run without handler?

`registerListener(SensorEventListener listener, Sensor sensor, int rate, Handler handler)`

`registerListener(SensorEventListener listener, Sensor sensor, int rate)`.

Comment: AFAIK the service will run on the UI thread, so i think you should use a handler, but im not 100%

Comment: That's exactly I am on doubt about that. I do not really want to run on UI thread cause I am afraid it might got killed after the application got shut down. I do not want that to happen.

Comment: The only way the service will be killed is if the system claims it for memory, if it is as vital as you say run it in a foreground service so it cant be destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the `Service` should implement `SensorEventListener`. You should rather create a new `Thread` inside a `Service` (since it is run in the UI Thread by default), a there yet another class designed for sensors data collection only. And have in mind that acceleration data is ***not*** being collected after the screen turns off. The easiest way around it is to add a `WakeLock`.